# Character Encoding Issue when activating Cloudflare

Tags: caching, character-encoding, cloudflare

When I activate cloudflare we have an encoding or caching issue whereby special characters appear all over the page.

**Header response with cloudflare deactivated:**

```
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,39,43,44"
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 8156
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 14:19:31 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 14:19:31 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: LiteSpeed
Set-Cookie: pmd_template=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/New/; domain=www.eastlondonbusinessdirectory.co.za
Set-Cookie: pmd_template=listimia; expires=Fri, 13-Sep-2019 14:19:31 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/New/; domain=www.eastlondonbusinessdirectory.co.za
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.33
```

**Header response with cloudflare activated:**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
CF-RAY: 50639e64dd188074-CPT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: zlib,gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 14:29:03 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 14:29:02 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: pmd_template=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/New/; domain=www.eastlondonbusinessdirectory.co.za
Set-Cookie: pmd_template=listimia; expires=Fri, 13-Sep-2019 14:29:02 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/New/; domain=www.eastlondonbusinessdirectory.co.za
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.33
X-Turbo-Charged-By: LiteSpeed
```

I believe I might need to make sure my origin server sends a header that tells the cache to serve pages based on the content encoding, but I'm not too sure if this logic is correct because with Cloudflare activated I only see Vary: User Agent? which is in fact ignored by Cloudflare... If the logic is correct then I'm not too sure how to go about fixing this. I have tried to add a page rule from Cloudflare to cache everything and also added the following in .htaccess

```
 </IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

but both does not work.

Any help will be much appreciated to get this issue resolved and will accept the answer

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare currently only [respects the Accept-Encoding vary header](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217343117-What-headers-can-I-vary-the-cache-on-).

If you want to vary based on other factors, you can either consider:

- [Custom caching](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004290387-Using-Custom-Cache-Keys) set up for Enterprise Plan
- "Bypass Cache" entirely using Page Rules
- Serve different content types from distinct URLs to continue leveraging caching
- [Workaround](https://workers.cloudflare.com/docs/reference/workers-concepts/using-cache/#interacting-with-the-cloudflare-cache) using Cloudflare Workers

Comment: hello Faiz thnak you for your time! So if cloudflare respects the Accept-Encoding vary header then should this not resolve the issue in .htaccess with the below? Or have i lost it??

    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Vary
    Header set Vary “Accept-Encoding”
    </ifModule>

Comment: do you have a sample URI where you're seeing the issue?

Comment: That support page has gone, but [this one](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/concepts/cache-control/#other) states "Cloudflare does not consider vary values in caching decisions. Nevertheless, vary values are respected when Vary for images is configured and when the vary header is vary: accept-encoding."